# Ordinals: if $\alpha < \omega^{\beta}$ then $\alpha + \omega^{\beta} = \omega^{\beta}$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I'm trying to proof that if $\alpha < \omega^{\beta}$ then $\alpha +  \omega^{\beta} =  \omega^{\beta}$, where $\omega$ is the least infinite ordinal.
I started with transfinite induction on $\beta$ by proving it for $\beta = 0$ and $\beta =1$.
But now I'm having problems with the successor and limit cases.
Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: This is a form of alpha being much less than w^b.

Comment: It is sufficient to show omega * alpha = alpha+alpha+alpha... is less than w^b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if $\beta=\gamma+1$ then $\alpha+\omega^{\gamma+1}=\alpha+\omega^\gamma\cdot\omega$. Now if $\alpha<\omega^\gamma$ we are done; otherwise we can write it as $\omega^\gamma\cdot n+\delta$, such that $\delta<\omega^\gamma$. And so $$\alpha+\omega^{\gamma+1}=\omega^\gamma\cdot n+\delta+\omega^\gamma\cdot\omega=\omega^\gamma\cdot n+(\delta+\omega^\gamma\cdot\omega)=\omega^\gamma\cdot n+\omega^\gamma\cdot\omega=\omega^\gamma(n+\omega)=\omega^{\gamma+1}.$$

The limit case can be solved using the fact that $\omega^\delta=\sup\{\omega^\gamma\mid\gamma<\delta\}$.

Comment: Thank you.
Can we say that $\alpha = \omega^{\gamma} + \delta$ when $\alpha \geq \omega^{\gamma}$, without using Cantor normal form?

Comment: Yes, we can. We can prove by transfinite recursion that if $\alpha\leq\beta$ then there exists a unique $\gamma$ such that $\alpha+\gamma=\beta$. If equality holds then $\gamma=0$, and if $\beta$ is sufficiently large we will have that $\delta=beta$. But that $\delta$ exists and is unique.

Comment: I don't understand why $\delta < \omega^\gamma$

Comment: @Roman: Yes, you're right.

Comment: @MrReese: As Roman remarks, $\alpha$ can be equal to something like $\omega^\gamma+\omega^\gamma$ in which case the first argument is slightly flawed, I have corrected it now, though.

Comment: Thank you Asaf, your help is wonderful.

Comment: @Roman: My pleasure!

Comment: Why does $  \delta+\omega^\gamma\cdot\omega=\omega^\gamma\cdot\omega$  follow from $ \delta+\omega^\gamma=\omega^\gamma$?

Comment: @Roman: $\delta+\omega^\gamma\cdot\omega= \delta+\omega^\gamma(1+\omega)= \delta+\omega^\gamma+\omega^\gamma\cdot\omega=\ldots$